# date range picker retrieve values in separate inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, daterangepicker

I'm using google charts to draw some report charts, but I need to allow the users to select a date range. I'm pretty new to this so I'm probably doing it the dumbest possible way.

My idea was the following:

Step 1: use a daterangepicker (I'm using this one: http://www.daterangepicker.com/ ) to get the desired range.

Step 2: "Ok, so I have this range displayed, what do I do with it?" So I though, "Hey, I'll try to slice the text end send it to 2 separate form inputs of type date. I could not figure out how to do it when pressing the apply button after selecting range, so I'm using a submit button. The idea is to pass the values and post it at the same time when I press the submit button (not sure if this is going to work).

Step 3: Post the input values and send it as a parameter to my model and then update the chart with the updated query to mySQL db.

Thing is, I'm pretty sure that there are way better ways to do it, for instance, using ajax so I don't need to reload the page (Keep in mind that that's pretty much all I know about ajax, I'm a first year programming student with zero programming background).  I'm using Codeigniter to communicate with the server.

Here is the code for the datepicker in my view:

```
  <div class="container">
  <div id="reportrange" class="col-sm-3 " style="background: #fff; cursor:pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; ">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
     <span id="thespan"></span> <b class="caret"></b>
  </div>

  <input type="date" id="dStart" name="dStart" value="" />
  <input type="date" id="dEnd" name="dEnd" value="" />
  <input onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>

</div>


<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("thespan").innerHTML;
    var res = str.slice(0, 10);
    document.getElementById("dStart").value = res;
    var res2 = str.slice(13, 23);
    document.getElementById("dEnd").value = res2;
 }
</script>




<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' - ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

    }

    cb(moment().startOf('week'), moment());

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

});
</script>
```

And here is the code in my model:

```
public function tester($startDate,$endDate) {

  $this->db->where('type_id', 7);
  // $this->db->where('entry_date >', '2016-05-11');
  // $this->db->where('entry_date <', 'curdate()', FALSE);
  $this->db->where('entry_date >=', '$startDate');
  $this->db->where('entry_date <=', '$endDate');
  $this->db->select('first_name, last_name, count(type_id) AS totals');
  $this->db->from('entries');
  $this->db->join('users', 'users.user_id = entries.user_id');
  $this->db->group_by('entries.user_id');
  $this->db->order_by('totals', 'DESC');
  $this->db->limit(3);
  $query = $this->db->get();

  return $query->result();

}
```

I see examples of date range picker being used and I could't find answer to my doubts online, which leads me to think that the solution is probably way more simple than what I'm trying to do. I'd like to get your opinions on how to approach this, keep in mind that I have basic php and mySQL knowledge, and almost zero js knowledge. Yes, I'm willing to learn and I've been studying everyday, but this app I'm developing is for my internship, so I can't take too long to finish it.

Thanks in advance.